# Deriving ui.Label and ui.Thumbnail from image List

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, thumbnail

I am trying to generate some *ui.Labels* and *ui.Thumbnail's* but having a hard time getting around the server-side and client-side issues after using .evaluate().

- I did some S5P preprocessing steps,
- generated medians, histograms,
- added those as properties to each image.

At the moment, I am having a List of images with image properties from median and histogram values. I used the  'Mosaic Editor' example to get a nice thumbnail grid setup but now I am failing to create a *ui.Label* and a *ui.Thumbnail* from my Image List. My issues are between line 151- 164.

- How do I access the image from a client-side object?
- How do I get the image property from the client-side object?

Full script is here https://code.earthengine.google.com/5d8d784dadb6195c6b355f8f0bc1f525

Answer (score 3):

This is too long script for me to read through properly, and I don't know what output is expected. I've just looked at the `updateUI()` and `makeThumbnail()` functions.

You are turning your list images into a client-side array. This means your images in turn will be client-side objects. Thumbnails cannot be created from these client-side image objects (they only contain the metadata of the image). Instead, you can use your server-side images for thumbnails, and evaluate just the IDs for your labels. Here's one way to approach it:

```
function updateUI(groups, thumbnailGrid) {
  thumbnailGrid.clear()
  var groupCollection = ee.ImageCollection(groups)
  var ids = groupCollection.aggregate_array('ID')
  ids.evaluate(function(ids) {
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
      var image = groupCollection.filterMetadata('ID', 'equals', id).first()
      var thumb = makeThumbnail(id, image)
      thumbnailGrid.add(thumb)
    })
  })
}

function makeThumbnail(id, image) {
  var thumbnailContainer = ui.Panel({
    layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),
    style: {
      backgroundColor: palette.transparent,
      border: BORDER_STYLE,
      padding: '4px',
      margin: '5px',
    },
  })

  var imageLabel = ui.Label(id) // ID doesn't show up
  thumbnailContainer.add(imageLabel)

  var thumbnail = ui.Thumbnail({
    image: image.select('NO2_1').visualize({
      min: 5,
      max: 30
    }), // Image doesn't show up
    params: {
      dimensions: THUMBNAIL_WIDTH,
      crs: 'EPSG:3857',
      format: 'png'
    },
    style: {
      width: THUMBNAIL_WIDTH + 'px',
      maxHeight: THUMBNAIL_WIDTH + 25 + 'px',
      backgroundColor: palette.transparent,
    }
  })
  thumbnailContainer.add(thumbnail)
  return thumbnailContainer
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Now I get the thumbnail, but instead of the ID, I would like to have the Name, which is already in the property (Line 171 - 173). Do you have an suggestion on how to proceed?   https://code.earthengine.google.com/9684f6bdfe9e08ecbe5546bb0ae6c042